# Laravel - Compare Dates

Tags: php, laravel

Im using Laravell framework.
This a banner for events, only showing the events that exist after the current date.

This is the current function on routes.php

```
Route::get('/banner', function()
{
    $date = time();
    $events = Event::where('date', '>', $date)->get();
    return View::make('banner')->with('events', $events);
});
```

In the view, this shows all the events, doesnt matter if is before or after the current date. And if i do this change:

```
$events = Event::where('date', '<', $date)->get();
```

This dont show anything.

The view is working good, my main problem here is that i cant find how to fix this.

Comment: Is your date column using a unix timestamp value? Or is it a DateTime type for the database?

Comment: Convert the two dates in exact format so that you can compare them.

Comment: Oh my god, i didnt realise that. I changed time() for date() and this already works.

Comment: Even better, follow Laravel standards and make use of the Carbon class. That will make your life a lot easier when dealing with date calculations.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this.

In your `Event` model add the following line.

```
protected $dates = ['date'];
```

By doing it when `Event` get saved the `date` will be saved as a [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) instance.

Then when you query you could simply do this.

```
$events = Event::where('date', '>', Carbon::now())->get();
```

make sure you import `Carbon` like this.

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
```

Refer [Fun with Dates by Laracasts](https://laracasts.com/lessons/fun-with-dates) for more details.